# How to set and get tint color on SVG programmaticaly in android?

Tags: java, android, tint

I have an `ImageView` which has an SVG as source example: `android:src="@drawable/bold_svg"`.

Now on click I want to set the tint color to `color accent` or return it to `white`. Two states.

What I have tried:

```
    myImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int currentColor, colorAccent;
            currentColor=ImageViewCompat.getImageTintList(myImageView).getDefaultColor();
            colorAccent=getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent);
            if (currentColor==colorAccent) {
                myImageView.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white_text_color));
            } else {
                myImageView.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
            }
        }
    });
```

It looks like every time I click the button, `currentColor` it does not change, so `else` is the only thing that is called! What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the answer something like this would work:

```
    myImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int currentColor, colorAccent;
            currentColor=ImageViewCompat.getImageTintList(myImageView).getDefaultColor();
            colorAccent=getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent);
            if (currentColor==colorAccent) {
                ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(ivBold, ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.white_text_color)));
            } else {
                ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(myImageView, ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorAccent)));
            }
        }
    });
```